# GA content experiment returns 403 with search traffic

Tags: google-analytics, internet-explorer-9, google-experiments

I installed GA content experiment code to my website and noticed that my server/site returns a “403 error/forbidden” message for search traffic that is using IE 9 (64 bit version).

When IE 9 user clicks a link from Google search result page, content experiment code is trying to redirect the user - -  but instead of test/variation page user gets 403 error.

Error only appears with IE 9 and search traffic (as far as I can tell). Other browsers (Mozilla and Chrome) can handle search traffic OK.

What would be correct approach/workaround for this?

---

Update: 
I did some more testing with 64 and 32 bit computers, and it  looks like there might be a bigger problem.

Win 7 / 64 bit

- OK - Chrome (V: 25.0.1364.97 m)

  OK - Mozilla FIrefox (V: 19)

  403 error - Opera (V: 12.14)

  403 error - IE9 (V: 9.0.8112.16421)

Win 7 / 32 bit

- 403 error - Safari (V: 5.1.7)

  403 error - Mozilla Firefox (V: 13.0.1)

  403 error - Chrome (V: 26.0.1410.19 beta-m)

  403 error - IE9 (V: 9.0.8112.16421)

  403 error - Opera (V: 11.61)

Ipad

- OK - Safari

  403 error - Chrome

Android phone (Galaxy nexus)

- OK - Android browser

  403 error - Chrome

  403 error - Opera

Error is standard 403 message:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /*XYZ* on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My hosting company told me that they had some “security feature”, that blocked GA content experiments code. They “whitelisted” content experiment code, and now everything is running OK.